# Read Arabic letters from unicode

Tags: json, excel, vba

At the moment, I am working on a JSON file that I could import to my excel worksheet but I have noticed that the name appears in weird way like that

```
{
      "name": "\u00d8\u00b3\u00d9\u0087\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0085 \u00d9\u0085\u00d8\u00ad\u00d9\u0085\u00d8\u00af",
      "timestamp": 1602577361
    },
```

I think the name is in Arabic letters. How can I convert such letters to readable Arabic letters?
Also when reading this in excel files, it is read in weird characters like that

```
Ø³Ù‡Ø§Ù… Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯
```

And this is the JSON file if you have a desire to have a look
http://jsoneditoronline.org/#right=local.yawuta&left=cloud.8c60f5b520dd4ba39df46337c8f6cd98

This is the UDF I used for imorting the JSON from the JSON file

```
Function GetJSON(ByVal sPath As String) As Object
    Dim Txt As String
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile (sPath)
        Txt = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
    Set GetJSON = JSONConverter.ParseJson(Txt)
End Function
```

Comment: How are you importing? And how is the data stored in file?

Comment: I am importing fro JSON file not from URL. The data is stored as in the right section of the posted link.

Comment: This is a UTF-8 encoded byte sequence that is then encoded as an escaped JSON string. When the bytes are so interpreted the string "سهام محمد" emerges. This is not a correct way of encoding this string, and likely the result of a Unicode-unaware process simply passing in a UTF-8 encoded string. This is fairly easy to reverse, but I have no idea how to do it in VBA.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Arabic letters is exactly as you deescribed. And when importing I used UTF-8 as Charset but that doesn't solve the problem. I have updated the question to add the UDF I am using.

Comment: Yes, it will do you no good to specify UTF-8 as the character set because that's not the problem -- the characters `u`, `0`, `0`, `d`, `8` and so on are all ASCII. The problem comes from the characters being incorrectly encoded in the JSON value, which cannot be solved by the `JSONConverter`.  The converter is doing its job properly, but it can't fix the fact that the input is broken.

Comment: Your best bet is to go back to the source of this file and point out that their output is broken. Failing that it looks like it's going to need some very nasty code that somehow converts the resulting string to a byte array and then invokes `MultiByteToWideChar` to interpret this as a UTF-8 string and convert it to UTF-16 so VBA can work with it again. Not something you want to bother with if it can at all be avoided.

Comment: The JSON file is downloaded from Facebook settings and I have downloaded the information of the friends!!

Comment: Unfortunately Facebook is not immune from having bugs in their implementations just because they're big...

Comment: Dunno if my old answer here is of any use given conversation above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62684714/6241235